# Using Maven Javadoc plugin can I create Javadocs only for specific package?

Tags: maven, maven-3, javadoc, maven-javadoc-plugin

Using Maven JavaDoc plugin, can I create Javadocs only for specific package? I have a parent module and want to generate Javadoc only for selected package in a child module. For example.

```
Parent
|
|__Module1
|____Package1
|____Package2
|
|__Module2
|____Package3
|____Package4
```

I want Javadocs only to work for Package2 under Module1

Answer (score 0):

Define the javadoc plugin in the parent e.g.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-M1</version>
    <configuration>
        <skip>true</skip>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

So, javadoc generation is available but it is skipped by default.

In `module1` declare the plugin with `skip` and `sourceFileIncludes`. For example:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <skip>false</skip>
        <sourceFileIncludes>
            <exclude>Package2/*.java</exclude>
        </sourceFileIncludes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

This enables javadoc generation for `module1` but only targets classes in `Package2`.

This is verified with v3.0.0-M1 of the Maven Javadoc plugin.